# Reversing the sections of a file based on blank line as a split

Tags: python

There is a file as below :

```
bash-4.1$ cat sample.txt

22|Data Structures|45
23|English|52
22|English|Level 2|51

26|Data Structures
23|Data Structures|61
26|English|81

23|English|52

21|English|5
23|English|52

bash-4.1$
```

The above file needs to be reversed at the blank like sections and output to be as below :

```
bash-4.1$ cat reversed_sample.txt

22|English|Level 2|51
23|English|52
22|Data Structures|45

26|English|81
23|Data Structures|61
26|Data Structures

23|English|52

23|English|52
21|English|5

bash-4.1$
```

How this to be accomplished in python ?

My attempt to identify lines which are empty and which are non empty :

```
count=0
fp=open("sample.txt")
blank=[]
full_line=[]
count=0
for line in fp:
    count=count+1
    x=line.strip()
    if (len(x)==0):
        blank.append(count)
    else:
        full_line.append(count)


print blank
print full_line
fp.close()
```

Comment: Did you make an attempt for yourself?

Comment: If you want to accomplish this in python why did you add sed tag?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one in GNU awk:

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS='' '{for(i=NF;i>=1;i--)print $i;print ""}' file
22|English|Level 2|51
23|English|52
22|Data Structures|45

26|English|81
23|Data Structures|61
26|Data Structures

23|English|52

23|English|52
21|English|5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open('sample.txt') as f:
    print(''.join(''.join(list(g)[::-1]) for _, g in groupby(f, key='\n'.__eq__)))
```

With your sample input, this outputs:

```
22|English|Level 2|51
23|English|52
22|Data Structures|45

26|English|81
23|Data Structures|61
26|Data Structures

23|English|52

23|English|52
21|English|5
```

Comment: `23|English|5221|English|5` will be the last line. You may want to fix that, as the last line doesn't have newline with it.

Comment: corrected. I mean if the input has newline at the end, then your output won't have that newline.

Comment: It will include a newline in the end if the input has one. It's just that SO won't allow a blank line to be formatted at the end of a code block with its MarkDown renderer. A newline in the end will become another group returned by `groupby` so it will be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple `sed` command

```
sed  -n '/^$/{x;p;d};G;h;$s/\n$//p' filename
```

**Output:**

```
22|English|Level 2|51
23|English|52
22|Data Structures|45

26|English|81
23|Data Structures|61
26|Data Structures

23|English|52

23|English|52
21|English|5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
with open("sample.txt", 'r') as f1:
    with open("sampleOut.txt", 'w') as f2:
        lineStack = []
        for l in f1:   # point 1
            print l
            if not l.strip():
                while (len(lineStack) > 0):
                    f2.write(lineStack.pop())
                f2.write("\n")
            else:
                lineStack.append(l)

        i = 0
        while (len(lineStack) > 0): # point 3
            f2.write(lineStack.pop())
            if (i == 0) :
                f2.write("\n") # point 2
                i = i + 1;
```

Points to note:

1. Create stack till the point empty line or EOF is found, use `not l.strip()` for that.
2. Last line doesn't contain newline with it. So you need to add it yourself.
3. At the end of `for l in f1:`, you may still be left with non-empty stack. So **don't forget** to flush its contents into out file.